# GLKQuaternion's not accessing w variable properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I'm trying to figure out an odd issue with GLKQuaternions. When attempting to print out the information for the Quaternions, the value for w = 0 every time. Although, in the debugger area, it clearly shows that -4.37114e-08 is stored in this value. I have no idea why. My print statement says:

```
NSLog(@"\n\nSLERP: Animation.Current:x:%f,y:%f,z:%f,w:%f and Animation.End:x:%f,y:%f,z:%f,w:%f", animation.Current.x, animation.Current.y, animation.Current.z, animation.Current.w, animation.End.x, animation.End.y, animation.End.z, animation.End.w);
```

My struct is

```
typedef struct{
    GLKQuaternion Start; //starting orientation
    GLKQuaternion End; //ending orientation
    GLKQuaternion Current; //current interpolated orientation
    float Elapsed; //time span in seconds for a slerp fraction between 0 and 1
    float Duration; //time span in seconds for a slerp fraction between 0 and 1
}Animation; //enables smooth 3D transitions
```

The debugger shows the following:

[image]

Note that animation.End.w = -4.37114e-08 while stating it = 0 in the debugger at the same moment. I had my break point setup right after the print statement. Does anyone know what would cause this? I think it's interfering with my calculations relating to the variable for w.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%f` outputs values to only 6 decimal places.

An an example, use `%.9f` to output to 9 decimal places.  Obviously, `-4.37114 * 10^-08` will require more than 6 decimal places so you will need to alter your formatting in your NSLog.

Comment: Woooow. Alright, I didn't even think about that. Oddly, I haven't ran into that issue since my early C days. I fixed it with [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:animation.End.w]. Unfortunately, I still have an issue in the code that I need to debug :(.

Comment: @TheGamingArt: It's an issue that I've missed in the past as well.  It's a very common issue as people always seem to forget.